# Is it possible to use an instance name instead of a port number in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I found out that in PostgreSQL you have ports which allow you to connect to your server. I guess this port is equivalent to SQL Server instance (e.g. MSSQLSERVER), but in SQL Server you can choose any instance name you want, unlike PostgreSQL which uses only port numbers.

Can I use instance names or something similar for PostgreSQL instead of port numbers?

Comment: *"I found out that in PostgreSQL you have ports"*  SQL Server uses these too... The *default* port is 1433, but you can run it on a different one if you want; this is especially true if you have multiple instances on the same host, as each instance on the same host **must** run on a different port.

Comment: See [Service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgservice.html). An instance is still based on a port but you can give it an alias, which I assume is what a SQL Server instance name is also.

Comment: All networked servers listen on a network interface and port.